# What is the story behind Kumbhakarna's sleep?

Tags: ramayana, ravana, kumbhakarna

I've heard a lot about the Sleep Lover, Kumbhakarna. Why was he sleeping for so many days continuously? Is there a story behind this?

Comment: Kumbhakarna did severe tapas with intention of asking for a boon from Brahma 'Nir-devatvam' - "No Devas". When he was about to speak, Saraswati Devi tied his tongue and it came out as "Nidr-evatvam" - Only Sleep.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Kumbhakarna was cursed by Lord Brahma.** This story is told by Vibhisana to Lord Rama in [this chapter](https://valmikiramayan.net/utf8/yuddha/sarga61/yuddha_61_frame.htm) of Yuddha Kanda of Valmiki Ramayana. In summary what happens is:

- Kumbhakarna soon after his birth begins to eat thousands of living creatures.
- Lord Indra was reported about this matter and he goes to punish Kumbhakarna.
- Kumbhakarna plucks tusk of Airavata and strikes in the chest of Indra with it.
- Lord Indra with other Gods goes to Lord Brahma to report on this matter.
- They tell that if Kumbhakarna eats in the present rate world will be devoid of creatures.
- Lord Brahma reaches to see Kumbhakarna and even he becomes afraid on seeing Kumbhakarna.
- Lord Brahma then curses Kumbhakarna as "You will be sleeping like dead from onwards."
- Ravana convinces Lord Brahma to give him some time for his sleeping and waking.
- Lord Brahma being convinced speaks -"He will indeed sleep for six months and wake-up for a day."
- Lord Brahma further says- "On that single day, this male demon, having starved for six months, will wander over the earth and eat the human race with his mouth wide open, like an augmented fire."

So, the reason behind the sleep of Kumbhakarna is the curse of Lord Brahma.

Here are the relevant verses from that chapter:

> एतेन जातमात्रेण क्षुधार्तेन महात्मना |
>   भक्षितानि सहस्राणि सत्त्वानाम् सुबहून्यपि || ६-६१-१३
>
> तेषु सम्भक्ष्यमाणेषु प्रजा भयनि पीडिताः |
>   यान्ति स्म शरणम् शक्रम् तमप्यर्थम् न्यवेदयन् || ६-६१-१४
>
> स कुम्भकर्णम् कुपितो महेन्द्रो जघान वज्रेण शितेन वज्री |
>   स शक्रवज्रभिहतो महात्मा | चचाल कोपाच्च भृशम् ननाद || ६-६१-१५
>
> तस्य नानद्यमानस्य कुम्भकर्णस्य रक्षसः |
>   श्रुत्वा निनादम् वित्रस्ताः प्रजा भूयो वितत्रसुः || ६-६१-१६
>
> ततः क्रुद्धो महेन्द्रस्य कुम्भकर्णो महाबलः |
>   निष्कृष्यैरावताद्दन्तम् जघानोरसि वासवम् || ६-६१-१७
>
> कुम्भकर्णप्रहारार्तो विजज्वाल स वासवः |
>   ततो विषेदुः सहसा देवा ब्रह्मर्षिदानवाः || ६-६१-१८
>
> प्रजाभिः सह शक्रश्च ययौ स्थानम् स्वयम्भूवः |
>   कुम्भकर्णस्य दौरात्म्यम् शशंसुस्ते प्रजापतेः || ६-६१-१९
>
> प्रजानाम् भक्षणम् चापि धर्षणम् च दिवौकसाम् |
>   आश्रमध्वंसनम् चापि परस्त्रीहरणम् तथा || ६-६१-२०
>
> एवम् प्रजा यदि त्वेष भक्षयिष्यति नित्यशः |
>   अचिरेणैव कालेन शून्यो लोको भविष्यति || ६-६१-२१
>
> वासवस्य वचः श्रुत्वा सर्वलोकपितामहः |
>   रक्षांस्यावाहयामास कुम्भकर्णम् ददर्श ह || ६-६१-२२
>
> कुम्भकर्णम् समीक्ष्यैव वितत्रास प्रजापतिः |
>   कुम्भकर्णमथाश्वस्तः स्वयम्भूरिदमब्रवीत् || ६-६१-२३
>
> **ध्रुवम् लोकविनाशाय पौलस्त्येनासि निर्मितः |
>   तस्मात्त्वमद्यप्रभृति मृतकल्पः शयिष्यसे ||** ६-६१-२४
>
> ब्रह्मशापाभिभूतोऽथ निपपाताग्रतः प्रभोः |
>   ततः परमसम्भ्रान्तो रावणो वाक्यमब्रवीत् || ६-६१-२५
>
> प्रवृद्धः काञ्चनो वृक्षः फलकाले निकृन्त्यते |
>   न नप्तारम् स्वकम् न्याय्यम् शप्तुमेवम् प्रजापते || ६-६१-२६
>
> न मिथ्यावचनश्च त्वम् स्वप्स्यत्येव न संशयः |
>   कालस्तु क्रियतामस्य शयने जागरे तथा || ६-६१-२७
>
> रावस्य वचः श्रुत्वा स्वयम्भूरिदमब्रवीत् |
>   शयिता ह्येष षण्मासानेकाहम् जागरिष्यति || ६-६१-२८
>
> एकेनाह्ना त्वसौ वीरश्च रन् भूमिम् बुभुक्षितः |
>   व्यात्तास्यो भक्षयेल्लोकान् सम्वृद्ध इव पावकः || ६-६१-२९
>
> "Soon after his birth, this great-souled demon, afflicted as he was by hunger, **ate thousands of living creatures.** While the living being were being eaten, the **frightened people sought refuge with Indra and even reported the matter** about him. That Mahendra wielding a thunder-bolt was enraged and struck Kumbhakarna with his weapon of the white thunderbolt. The great souled **Kumbhakarna struck by Indra's thunderbolt** was quite agitatated at it and roared loudly with anger. Hearing the roar of that Kumbakarna, the demon, who was howling loudly, the grigthened people were further frightened. Enraged as he was on Mahendra, the mighty **Kumbhakarna then pulled out a tusk of Airavata, Indra's elephant and struck it into Indra's chest.** That Devendra, tormented by the hit of Kumbhakarna, was burning with rage. The celestials, Brahmanical sages and demons were suddenly aggrieved. Even Indra with his people went to the abode of Brahma the Lord of creation. **They informed about the evil-mind of Kumbhakarna to Brahma, how he devoured the living creatures**, his assault on celestials, the destroyal of hermitages and his taking away of others' wives. If he eats away the created beings continuously like this, the world will become desolate just soon after some time. On hearing the words of Indra, Brahama, the great grandfather of the entire world, called for the demons and saw Kumbhakarna too along with them. **Just on seeing Kumbhakarna even Brahma was frightened. Thereafter on restoring his confidence, Brahma cursed Kumbhakarna as follows: "It is sure that you were created by visravasa for the destroyal of people. On that account, you will be sleeping apparently dead from now onwards."** Humbled by Brahma's curse, Kumbhakarna then fell down in front of Ravana. Thereupon, the highly perplexed **Ravana spoke the following words:** "O Brahma! You are cutting off a well-grown golden tree, just at the time of yielding its fruit. It is not fair on your part to curse your own great grandson like this.Your words can never prove to be in vain. There is no doubt about it. He will have to sleep certainly. Let some space of time be fixed for his sleeping and waking." **Hearing the words of Ravana, Brahma spoke as follows: "He will indeed sleep for six months and wake-up for a day. On that single day, this male demon, having starved for six months, will wander over the earth and eat the human race with his mouth wide open, like an augmented fire."**

Comment: Great and we'll explained.

Comment: Well explained answer. Good to see A poster who posted question in 2014, is active now too to accept the answer.

Comment: Welcome back to Hinduism Stack Exchange! Haha :)

Answer (score 9):

The story is told in [this excerpt](http://gdurl.com/D2Di) from the Uttara Kanda of the Ramayana.  Ravana was told by his father Vishravas that he should attain the status of his half-brother Kubera the god of wealth.  (Kubera and Ravana were both sons of Vishravas, but they had different mothers.). So Ravana, along with his brothers Kumbhakarna and Vibhishana, went to the hermitage of Gokarna to engage in Tapasya (deep meditation).  Here is what Kumbhakarna in particular did:

> And Kumbhakarna, putting forth his best energies, constantly abode in the path of righteousness. And remaining in the midst of five fires in summer,he practised austerities, and in the rainy season, soaked in water (poured down) by clouds, he sat in the heroic attitude.* And in winter he always remained in the water. Thus passed away ten thousand years of that one putting forth exertions in behalf of religion, and established in the path of honesty.

His brothers engaged in similarly arduous activities, until finally Brahma appeared before them and offered them each a boon.  Ravana asked for immortality, but was denied, so he asked that he would "be incapable of being slain by birds and serpents, Yakshas, Daityas, Danavas and Rakshasas, and the deities."  Vibhishana asked to always be righteous, so Brahma granted him immortality.

Finally Brahma went to ask Kumbhakarna what boon he wanted, but then at that very moment the gods approached Brahmna and begged him not to grant Kumbhakarna any boons for fear that he would cause even more mayhem:

> On Kumbhakarna thou shouldst. confer no boons, since thou knowest in what manner doth this wicked-minded one frighten people. And, O Brahma, seven Apsaras in Nandana, ten
> attendants of Mahendra, as well as sages and human beings, have been devoured by this one. Considering what this Rakshasa did when he had not obtained any boon whatever, if he obtain one now he shall eat up the three worlds. Do thou then, O lord having immeasurable prowess, pretending to give him a boon, give stupifaction (instead). Thereby the welfare of people would be secured, and the honor of this one too shall be maintained

So Brahma asked his wife Saraswati, who is the goddess of speech among other things, to take control of Kumbhakarna's speech and make him wish for something that would benefit the gods rather than harming them:

> And [Brahma] the lord of creatures, on having her, spake unto Saraswati, "O Vani!  Be thou the goddess of speech of this foremost of Rakshasas, favorable unto the deities." Having said "So be it," she entered (within Kumbhakarna's throat) ; and [Brahma] said, "O Kumbhakarna, O mighty-armed one, do thou ask for the boon that thou wouldst have." Hearing those words, Kumbhakarna said, "O god of gods, **my wish is that I may sleep for a good many years**." Thereupon, saying "So be it," Brahma along with the celestials went away; and the goddess, Saraswati, also again left the Rakshasa. And on Brahma accompanied by the deities going to the celestial regions, he was renounced by Saraswati, and then he regained his consciousness. And then the wicked-minded Kumbhakarna sorrowfully thought, "What is this speech that has to-day come out from my lips ? Meseems I had then been stupified by the deities that had come."

That is how Kumbhakarna was cursed with sleeping.

It should also be noted that in the Yuddha Kanda of the Ramayana, Vibhishana gives an account of Kumbhakarna's sleeping curse where he neglects to mention the part about the Tapasya, but he does discuss how [the curse was lessened](http://www.valmikiramayan.net/utf8/yuddha/sarga61/yuddha_61_frame.htm) to being able to be awake once every six months:

> Humbled by Brahma's curse, Kumbhakarna then fell down in front of Ravana. Thereupon, the highly perplexed Ravana spoke the following words: "O Brahma! You are cutting off a well-grown golden tree, just at the time of yielding its fruit. It is not fair on your part to curse your own great grandson like this. Your words can never prove to be in vain. There is no doubt about it. He will have to sleep certainly. Let some space of time be fixed for his sleeping and waking."
>
> Hearing the words of Ravana, Brahma spoke as follows: "He will indeed sleep for six months and wake-up for a day.  On that single day, this male demon, having starved for six months, will wander over the earth and eat the human race with his month wide open, like an augmented fire."

But the thing is Kumbhakarna was [already awake](http://www.valmikiramayan.net/utf8/yuddha/sarga12/yuddha_12_frame.htm) close to the beginning of the war between Rama and Ravana.  But Ravana, in his desperation to beat Rama, awoke Kumbhakarna only [nine days](http://www.valmikiramayan.net/utf8/yuddha/sarga60/yuddhasans60.htm#Verse17) after he went to sleep.  It was Kumbhakarna's being woken up at a time when he was supposed to be asleep that led to his death.

Comment: The most interesting bit of the story is lost with English translations. Kumbhakarna did severe tapas with intention of asking for a boon 'Nir-devatvam' - "No Devas". When he was about to speak, Devi tied his tongue and it came out as "Nidra-evatvam" - Only Sleep.

Answer (score 6):

Kumbhakarna was able to eat a lot of food in his single meal since his childhood. The quantity of his single meal is equal to the food you can say like your whole life's food quantity.

Because of this the Devas from swarg ( heaven ) were in very much tension that if he lives for more like this then the whole earth's food will be finished.

While Kumbakarna was doing tapas with his other brother Ravana & Vibhishan, when Lord bramha asked Kumbakarna for bless, at that time Godess Saraswati placed on his tongue and instead of "Indrasan"  ( the thrown of Lord Indra from Heaven ), he spoke "Nindrasan" which means Bed. So Lord Bramha blessed him for same. So because of Nindrasan, he needed to sleep 6 months and then he could wakeup for single day. After this again he needed to sleep for next 6 months.

Please watch the first 5 minutes from this episode [Ramayan Episode 62](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rfmDlFLMiqA), I answer based on this video. If you know Hindi language, then good otherwise there are subtitles in the video, that will help you.

Comment: TV shows are not an acceptable reference.  See here: http://meta.hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/114/36

Comment: how can you verify that the online resource is 100% accurate ? I too agree that TV show are not 100% accurate but these shows are based on some sources only. Nobody creates story from his/her mind.

Comment: These TV shows take a lot of artistic license, so they're not reliable sources.

Comment: Agree,but my point is How can you say that the source link you provided is 100% accurate ? `Trust` & `Faith` are the only things we need have.

Comment: Well, it'a hard to confirm anything with 100% certainty, but the point is that some sources are more reliable and trustworthy than others.  The link I gave is an excerpt directly from Hindu scripture (the Uttara Kanda of the Valmiki Ramayana).  Now it is a (reliable) English translation, so it's possible that there could be some translator error, but the probability of that sort if error is much lower than the probability of artistic license on a Tv show (which occurs all the time.  So the community has decided that scriptural citations are acceptable and TV shows aren't.

Answer (score 0):

Kumbakarna is brother of Ravana. Both started to do tapas in praise of Brahma. Gods who were feared after Kumbakarna's strength, pleaded Goddess Saraswathi to influence Kumbakarna and restrict him from getting mighty boons. When Brahma came descended to bless the duo, She then entered on to the tongue of Kumbakarna and made him ask to bless him with 6 months of sleep and 6 months for feeding himself!

Comment: Could you add some more points to your answer?