# Why was Mother Saraswati so unfair with KumbhaKarna?

Tags: ramayana, dharma, saraswati, kumbhakarna

We all know the story that to stop KumbhaKarna from asking boon from Brahma, all Gods eulogized Saraswati to enter KumbhaKarna's mouth to ask- "I may sleep for years". **And Mother Saraswati did it!**

Why were Gods so unfair, specially the kind Mother of Universe Saraswati?

Even if one asks for boon- "I may kill Shiva, Brahma and Vishnu." This boon is also to be fulfilled by God, as one has complete right over this also (
even though it is unimaginably sinful).

So why would Gods play so unjust befooling KumbhaKarna, and specially Mother Saraswati, the Goddess of purity(of truth, dharma), would do such a culpable thing.

Comment: Possible this question already has  answered - https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/2161/what-is-the-story-behind-kumbhakarnas-sleep

Comment: See @keshav sirnivasan answer.

Comment: @SwiftPushkar that was no answer to my question. Even if KumbhaKarna was wicked, could have led a lot of ruin, then also this was not fair for Mother Saraswati and other Gods to play unfair with him. If these are Gods, who have no justice, then whom to worship? Please note, there is no offence to Hinduism or any God/Goddess, the question is about justice.

Comment: "This pasage is what I was pointing out as possible answer. "Finally Brahma went to ask Kumbhakarna what boon he wanted, but then at that very moment the gods approached Brahmna and begged him not to grant Kumbhakarna any boons for fear that he would cause even more mayhem:"

Comment: Stoping some demon from causing further destruction is not "UNFAIR" according to gods.Its their duty to protect mankind from daemonic forces at any cost and in any way.

Comment: @SwiftPushkar When Brahma gave boon to MahiShasur- you will be unconquerable except from women. Where did go the Devas' concern to save Humankind from demonic forces?

Comment: " Mahishasura performed austerities (tapas) to Brahma, propitiating Brahma to confer upon him immortality. Brahma refused him the boon of immortality; instead, Brahma gave him a boon such that his death would happen only at the hands of a woman. Mahishasura imagined that this was the equivalent of immortality."

Comment: @SwiftPushkar KumbhaKarna also performed a lot of austerities. Brahma could have given him something else, but a full of 6 months sleep and only 1 day wake, is very unjust

Comment: Kumbhakarna's flaw is that he was asking a boon from the very gods who he used to eat and kill. He was a cannibal Raksasa who consumed Deva flesh as his meat.